# Drupal Relative Path

Tags: path-aliases, .htaccess, uri, navigation

I am using Drupal 7. The website I am on was configured previously. My goal is to add an external link to a page. However, i am having trouble. Every link I add to any page is read as a relative link. For example, if I have the following code:

`<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>`

The URL in the browser becomes: dev.mysite.com/#http://www.google.com
But, I want the URL to be http://www.google.com

First, Can i fix this using PHP?
Second, Is this something the Pathauto Module is responsible for, or maybe the Rewrite module? Both are enabled on the site
Lastly, is it a mod rewrite issue? If so, how would i fix it?

Comment: How are you adding this link? Is there a link field or are you adding it to the node body?

Comment: No, there is not a link field. It is being added to the node body using the anchor tag. <a href="">text</a>.

Comment: Pathauto would not be responsible for touching any kind of links inside a node body.

Answer (score 2):

You must have some kind of text filter that is acting on your text
see what filters are applied here:
admin/config/content/formats

Or you are using a WYSIWYG editor to add the link.  If that is ckeditor, you have to set relative links to "Other" rather than http in the link editor.